# Python Threading - _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, multithreading

I have following code:

```
def selectstrategydata():
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user_app_strategy where status = 'ACTIVE' and strategy_id = 1")

    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    if mycursor.rowcount == 1:
        strategy_status = 'active'
    for x in myresult:
      print(x)

t = threading.Thread(target=selectstrategydata, args=())
t1 = threading.Thread(target=selectstrategydata, args=())

t.start()
t1.start()
t.join()
t1.join()
```

When I run this code I get below error in traceback:

> Exception in thread Thread-1 (selectstrategydata): Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line
> 633, in cmd_query
> self._cmysql.query(
> _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\python\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "D:\python\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "D:\Application\automated_trader\temp.py", line 94, in
> selectstrategydata
> mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user_app_strategy where status = 'ACTIVE' and strategy_id = 1")   File
> "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line
> 330, in execute
> result = self._cnx.cmd_query(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\opentelemetry\context_propagation.py",
> line 77, in wrapper
> return method(cnx, *args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line
> 641, in cmd_query
> raise get_mysql_exception( mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection
> to MySQL server during query

however for one thread I get the result for others I get error